# Windows 10 Home Ed - Base Filtering Engine won't start (Access Denied) Error 5

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-defender, windows-services

I am running **Windows 10 Home Edition**. I cannot run **Windows Defender Firewall** because it is dependent on **Base Filtering Engine** which is not running, does not run on start-up and I cannot run as administrative Windows User (MS account).

When I try to start the service from **services.msc**.

[image]

I inspected the dependencies and they are both running.

[image]

I have tried adding `Full Control` permission in the registry for `NT SERVICE\BFE` with inheritance, based on [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-us/d8e59632-fca9-4bbd-b748-881af144706a/access-denied-base-filter-engine) and another:

- `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE`
- `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent`
- `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy`

I downloaded **ProcessMonitor.exe** per recommendation from the Microsoft website hoping I would see an 'Access Denied' log that could give me more data. The tool showed no rows with 'Access Denied' flag at all, I tried to start the service several times, nothing.

I tried a system restore from a restore point I created the other day, this did not resolve the issue.

I tried to copy the permission configuration from a working machine but this did not resolve the error suggesting that there might be other permissions needed, but I would not know where to look.

I even applied a `Full Control` permission to the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE` for `Everyone`. I still couldn't start it. I removed this afterwards of course.

I ran `sfc /scannow` in an elevated **cmd** instance, disk is integral just to make sure.

I also ran an offline malware/virus scan using built-in Windows tools which returned nothing.

I don't really know enough about this to solve it. Broadly, this happened with other services and I had to manual resolve permissions to kick them off. It is Sunday night and I need this machine ready for work on Monday morning so I would prefer to not have to reinstall from scratch (lot of setup required).

Comment: It’s insanely difficult to disable Windows Defender Firewall, the fact you have effectively done this, tells me it’s likely malware to blame.  You might not have intended to disabled the service in question, but the fact other requirements services also were not automatically started, indicates a severe system corruption issue

Comment: I did an offline malware/virus scan which i forgot to mention. You are probably right though, I physically removed 2 disks which were constantly at 100% and preventing me from running my machine.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image

Comment: In the end I decided to pull out drives suspect drives, reformat my USD disk and redownload and install the Win-10 installer on it. I reformatted my SSD HD on the machine in question. I then reinstalled Win-10 from scratch. It is behaving well for now. Although I noticed today that 'reputation protection was turned off', I will keep an eye on this.